# GoJS strokeWidth giving a black box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gojs

I am using react JS. In my link template, I tried following things

1. A simple path

```
      go.Link,
      { curve: go.Link.Bezier },
      new go.Binding("relinkableFrom", "canRelink").ofModel(),
      new go.Binding("relinkableTo", "canRelink").ofModel(),
      $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "Standard", scale: 1.5 })
    )
```

Result - a default link as expected
[image]

2. Links with a thick stroke

```
diagram.linkTemplate = $(
      go.Link,
      { curve: go.Link.Bezier },
      new go.Binding("relinkableFrom", "canRelink").ofModel(),
      new go.Binding("relinkableTo", "canRelink").ofModel(),      
      $(go.Shape), 
      $(go.Shape, {strgokeWidth : 4}),
      $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "Standard", scale: 1.5 })
    )
```

Result - A black box in the middle of links
[image]

I just want to increase the thickness of the links.
I tried adding mouse events

```
        mouseEnter: function(e, link) { link.path.strokeWidth = 4; },
        mouseLeave: function(e, link) { link.path.strokeWidth = 4; }
      },
```

That also works! could anyone help me with this? I do not want black boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link template is:

```
diagram.linkTemplate =
  $(go.Link,
    { curve: go.Link.Bezier },
    new go.Binding("relinkableFrom", "canRelink").ofModel(),
    new go.Binding("relinkableTo", "canRelink").ofModel(),      
    $(go.Shape), // the one Link.path Shape
    $(go.Shape, { strokeWidth : 4}),
    $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "Standard", scale: 1.5 })
  )
```

(I have fixed your typo naming the "strokeWidth" property.)

First, if for a **Shape** you don't set the **GraphObject.desiredSize** (or equivalently, the **GraphObject.width** and **height**) to real numbers, and if its containing Panel doesn't impose any constraints on the size, and if you haven't set **Shape.geometry** or **geometryString**, then the default size will be 100x100, which as you have seen is obvious enough to tell programmers that they forgot something.

Normally such Shapes would be used as labels on the Link.  That's why you are seeing the (default) Shape at the middle of the link's path.

However from your description it appears that you want there to be more than one **Link.path** **Shape** that automatically get the **Geometry** computed by the Link from the Link's route.  By default there is only one **Link.path**, so if you want there to be more than one such Shape, you have to set **GraphObject.isPanelMain** to true on each such Shape.

Please read: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/links.html#EasierClickingOnLinks